# Flow doesn't update Composable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-stateflow

I faced the following problem:

There's the registration screen, which has several input fields on it. When a user enters something, the value is passed to ViewModel, set to screen state and passed back to the screen via StateFlow. From the composable, I'm observing this StateFlow. The problem is that Composable is not invalidated after emitting the new value to the Flow.

Here's the ViewModel code:

```
class RegistrationViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

    private val screenData = CreateAccountRegistrationScreenData.init()

    private val _screenDataFlow = MutableStateFlow(screenData)
    internal val screenDataFlow = _screenDataFlow.asStateFlow()

    internal fun updateFirstName(name: String) {
        screenData.firstName = name
        updateScreenData()
    }

    private fun updateScreenData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _screenDataFlow.emit(screenData.copy())
        }
        println()

    }

}
```

Here's the composable code:

```
@Composable
fun RegistrationScreen(navController: NavController, stepName: String) {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    val viewModel: RegistrationViewModel by rememberInstance()

    val screenData by viewModel.screenDataFlow.collectAsState()

    Scaffold {
        ConstraintLayout(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTapGestures(onTap = {
                        focusManager.clearFocus()
                    })
                },
        ) {
            val (
                textTopLabel,
                textBottomLabel,
                tfFirstName,
                tfLastName,
                tfEmail,
                tfPassword,
                btnNext
            ) = createRefs()

            ...
            RegistrationOutlinedTextField(
                value = screenData.firstName ?: "",
                constraintAsModifier = {
                    constrainAs(tfFirstName) {
                        top.linkTo(textBottomLabel.bottom, margin = Padding30)
                        start.linkTo(parent.start)
                        end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    }
                },
                label = { Text("First Name", style = PoppinsNormalStyle14) },
                leadingIcon = {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_user_login),
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
                },
                onValueChange = { viewModel.updateFirstName(it) }
            )
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're mutating your state, so the equals used in the flow always returns true.

Change this

```
internal fun updateFirstName(name: String) {
    screenData.firstName = name
    updateScreenData()
}

private fun updateScreenData() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _screenDataFlow.emit(screenData.copy())
    }
    println()

}
```

to

```
internal fun updateFirstName(name: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _screenDataFlow.emit(screenData.copy(firstName = name))
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that copy method should return the new instance and it's hashcode is not the same as state instance, no?

Comment: When you mutate the state you are mutating the instance in your flow. So when you emit a copy, it's the same already.

Answer (score 4):

In your case your `MutableStateFlow` holds a link to a mutable value, that's why when you pass the value which `hashcode`(which is calculated on all field values) is identical, the flow doesn't update the value.

Check out [Why is immutability important in functional programming?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-immutability-important-in-functional-programming)

`data class` is a nice tool to be used, which will provide you all `copy` out of the box, but you should emit using `var` and only use `val` for your fields to avoid mistakes.

Also, with `MutableStateFlow` you always have access to `value`, so you don't need to store it in a separate variable:

```
class RegistrationViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

    private val _screenDataFlow = MutableStateFlow(CreateAccountRegistrationScreenData())
    internal val screenDataFlow = _screenDataFlow.asStateFlow()

    internal fun updateFirstName(name: String) {
        _screenDataFlow.update { screenData ->
            screenData.copy(firstName = name)
        }
    }
}
```