# Why recomposition doesn't happen when TextFieldValue changes

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-stateflow, compose-recomposition

My ViewModel

```
val names =
    listOf(
        "valeria",
        "Daniela",
        "Isabella",
        "Liam",
        "Noah",
        "Jack",
        "Oliver",
        "Ava",
        "Sophia",
        "Amelia"
    )

private val _namesList = MutableStateFlow(names)
val namesList = _namesList.asStateFlow()


fun getFilteredNames(state: MutableState<TextFieldValue>) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val searchedText = state.value.text
        _namesList.value =
            if (searchedText.isEmpty()) {
                names
            } else {
                val resultList = ArrayList<String>()
                for (item in names) {
                    if (item.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())
                            .contains(searchedText.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()))
                    ) {
                        resultList.add(item)
                    }
                }
                Log.d("List: ", namesList.value.toString())
                resultList
            }
    }
}
```

Recomposition doesn't happen for some reason.

```
 val viewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()
 val names = viewModel.namesList.collectAsState()
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize().background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
    ) {
        items(names.value.size) {
            SearchListItem(names.value[it]) {}
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm leaving some links to my answers regarding `SnapshotStateList` in case you haven't solve this yet. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74134219/jetpack-compose-lazycolumn-not-updating-with-mutablelist/74134269#74134269), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74343623/jetpack-compose-lazy-column-not-recomposing-with-list/74343738#74343738), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74144053/lazycolumn-does-not-update-when-deleting-an-item/74144210#74144210)

Answer (score 0):

Once I had the same question (you can see it and some other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70146178/flow-doesnt-update-composable)). if shortly, flow is updated only when you emit the new object to it (with different hashcode than the last emitted item). and you are updating the same list and then trying to pass it to flow. if you will create the copy of the list and emit this copy, everything will work ok, as it is already another object

Comment: Log.d("List: ", namesList.hashCode().toString())  shows different hashcode each time the TextFieldValue changes but the recomposition still doesn't happen!

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure how are you using this callback to get more items. Simplified it would be like:

```
val mutableNamesList = MutableStateFlow(listOf<String>())
val namesList = mutableNamesList.asStateFlow()

@Composable
fun NamesList() {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    TextField(value = text, onValueChange = { newTextValue ->
        text = newTextValue
        coroutineScope.launch {
            mutableNamesList.value = ( mutableNamesList.value + newTextValue)
        }
    })
   val list =  namesList.collectAsState().value
    LazyColumn {
        items(list) { item ->
            Text(text = item)
        }
    }
}
```

Just, I used this import:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did, the names list gets updated on TextFieldValue change in the ViewModel, but the change doesn't reflect in the LazyColumn after calling  val names = viewModel.namesList.collectAsState()

Comment: Then try to move val names = viewModel.namesList.collectAsState().value outside LazyColumn

Comment: It's already outside the LazyColumn

Comment: I moved the search view from the TopAppBar the recomposition works fine, but How can I make it with the SearchView (TextField) in the TopAppBar

Comment: I can not know what is structure of your code. Probably this is what you need https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting