# Jetpack Compose: LazyColumn not updating with MutableList

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, mutablelist, compose-recomposition

I am trying to strikethrough a text at the click of a button using `Jetpack Compose` but the UI is **not updating**.

I have tried to set a button and on the click of a button, **deletedTasks** gets updated and if my task is in **deletedTasks** then it should show up with a strikethrough.

This change only happens manually but I want it to be automatic

I am not sure how to go about this. This is my first time trying `Jetpack Compose`, any help would be appreciated

```
@Composable
fun toDoItem(title: String, category: String, task: Task) {

    val rememberTask = remember { mutableStateOf(deletedTasks) }

    Surface(...) {

        Column (...) {

            Row {
                Column (...) {
                    if (!deletedTasks.contains(task)){
                        Text(text = title, style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4.copy(
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                        ))
                    } else {
                        Text(text = title, style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4.copy(
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                        ), textDecoration = TextDecoration.LineThrough)
                    }
                }
                IconButton(onClick = {
                    rememberTask.value.add(task)
                }) {
                    Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Check, contentDescription =  "Check")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Composable
fun recyclerView(tasks: MutableList<Task>) {
    LazyColumn (modifier =  Modifier.padding(vertical = 10.dp, horizontal = 80.dp)) {
        items(items = tasks) {task ->
            toDoItem(task.title, task.category, task)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `MutableList<>`, which is not recommended for any collection use-cases in `Jetpack Compose`. I would advice changing it to a `SnapshotStateList`.

Your recyclerView composable would look like this

```
@Composable
fun recyclerView(tasks: SnapshotStateList<Task>) { ... }
```

and somewhere where you set things up (e.g `ViewModel`) would be like

```
tasks = mutableStateListOf<Task>( ... )
```

Using `SnapshotStateList` will guarantee an "update" or `re-composition` with any normal list operation you do to it such as,

- `list.add( <new task> )`
- `list.remove( <selected task> )`
- `list[index] = task.copy()` <- idiomatic way of udpating a list

There is also `SnapshotStateMap` which is for `Map key~value` pair use-case.

But if you are curious as to how you would update your `LazyColumn` with an ordinary `List`, you would have to re-create the entire `MutableList<Task>` so that it will notify the composer that an update is made because the `MutableList<Task>` now refers to a new reference of collection of tasks.