# Kotlin flow not updating UI

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow

I have a list of news items in `jetpack compose` and I want to show in the UI that the news item is liked by the user.
So I have:
viewModel:

```
    private val _newsList = MutableStateFlow(ArrayList<NewsDto>())
    var newsList = _newsList.asStateFlow()
        private set
```

my composable:

```
    var newslist = viewModel.newsList.collectAsState()
    ...
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(
                brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                    colors = listOf(
                        Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                        Color(0xFFF2F3F7)
                    )
                ), shape = RectangleShape
            ), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ) {
 if (newslist.value.isEmpty()) {
            items(4) {
                NewsSkeleton()
            }
        } else {
//            show news
            items(newslist.value.size) {
                NewsItem(newsItem = newslist.value[it],
                    onNewsFavoriteClicked = {
                        if (it.isFavorite){
                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                viewModel.removeNewsFavorite(it.id, context = context)
                            }
                        } else {
                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                viewModel.setNewsFavorite(it.id, context = context)
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    onNewsLikeClicked = {
                        if (!it.isLiked){
                            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

                                viewModel.likeNews(it)
                            }
                        } else {
                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                viewModel.unlikeNews(it)
                            }
                        }
                    })
            }
        }
}
```

Now when I click the like button, I send a request to the server and update the UI:
viewModel

```
    suspend fun setNewsLiked(index: Int) {
//        _newsList.value =
//            ArrayList(_newsList.value.apply { this[index] = this[index].copy(isLiked = true) }.toImmutableList())
        _newsList.emit(ArrayList(_newsList.value.apply { this[index] = this[index].copy(isLiked = true) }.toImmutableList()))
    }

    suspend fun likeNews(newsDto: NewsDto) {
        val response = AuthenticationManager.fetchToken(context = context)
            ?.let { likeNewsUseCase.likeNews(LikeNewsDTO(newsId = newsDto.id), it) }
        if (response?.isSuccessful == true) {
            setNewsLiked(_newsList.value.indexOfFirst { it.id == newsDto.id })
        }
    }
```

If I relaunch the app, the UI is updated. But not when I hit the button...
**Edit**:

```
@Composable
fun NewsItem(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, newsItem: NewsDto, onNewsFavoriteClicked: ((NewsDto) -> Unit)? = null,
             onNewsLikeClicked: ((NewsDto) -> Unit)? = null) {
         LazyRow(...){
...
item {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(32.dp)
                        .background(
                            color = Color(if(newsItem.isLiked) 0xFFF2F3F7 else 0x2FB6B0), shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
                        ).clickable(){
                                     onNewsLikeClicked?.invoke(newsItem)
                        }, contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_like),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `setNewsLiked` is being called?

Comment: Yes. I'm sure it is being called.

Comment: Is `toImmutableList` a custom extension you written?

Comment: No, I haven't written it my self.

Comment: Can you show the `//Lazy column and rest of the stuff...` ?

Comment: Just edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to explain why your code doesn't work. But it seems Jetpack Compose do not like `ArrayList` very well, refer to this post: [Jetpack Compose: LazyColumn not updating with MutableList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74134219/jetpack-compose-lazycolumn-not-updating-with-mutablelist)

If you like to stick with `ArrayList`, doing a `map` instead would work.

```
suspend fun setNewsLiked(index: Int) {
    _newsList.emit(ArrayList(_newsList.value.map { if (it.id == index) it.copy(isLiked = true) else it }))
}
```

Yet I cannot explain why because the net result on the new `_newsList.value` looks identical to me. Both are new instants of `ArrayList` containing same instants of unchanged items and a new instant of the changed item. Appreciate if someone could explain it.

### Edit

`MutableStateFlow.emit()` eventually does a [equality check](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/1a0287ca3fb5d6c59594d62131e878da4929c5f8/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/StateFlow.kt#L327) to avoid setting identical value. By doing `_newsList.value.apply { this[index] = this[index].copy(isLiked = true) }`, you have already changed the content of `_newsList.value` before emitting. Then when you call emit, it check for its current value (which have its content been changed beforehand) against the new value (which although is a new instant, its content is equal to the current value). Therefore, the new state doesn't get emitted because it thinks it was equal to the current state.

If you want to update the state of a `MutableStateFlow` deriving form its current value, make sure to not change the current value.